# How to add a selected attr to the underscore template

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I'm using the underscore template to render a dropdown options. I'm looking to display the text of selected dropdown option. Here is the template I'm using:

```
<select id = "selectedRegion"><% _.each(data.region,function(field){ %><option value ="<%= field.id%>" ><%= field.name %></option>'
       +' <% }) %></select><% }%>
```

I'm wondering how in underscore can I mention the 'selected' attr. as in html like:

```
<option value="N" selected>New york</option>
```

I tried this way, but no luck

```
<select id = "selectedRegion"><% _.each(data.region,function(field){ %><option value ="<%= field.id%>" selected= <%= field.selected %> ><%= field.name %></option>'
       +' <% }) %></select><% }%>
```

Here is the Js:

```
var regions = [];
var values = $('#selectedRegion').children('option').each(function(i, e){
 regions.push({id:e.value, name:$(e).html(),select:$(e).is(':selected')?true:false});

});
```

Anyone has any ideas on how this can be achived??

Thanks!

Comment: Note that you used `select` as the property name in your JS code, but try to access a property called `selected` in the teamplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you have

```
selected= <%= field.selected %>
```

Try

```
<%= (field.selected) ? "selected" : "" %>
```

This will output the value of `selected` if the field is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your JS:

```
var regions = [];
var values = $('#selectedRegion').children('option').each(function(i, e){
 regions.push({id:e.value, name:$(e).html(),selected:$(e).is(':selected')?'selected':''});
});
```

And this for your template:

```
'<select id = "selectedRegion"><% _.each(data.region,function(field){ %><option value="<%= field.id%>" <%= field.selected %> ><%= field.name %></option>'
       +' <% }) %></select><% }%>
```

This will store the needed HTML attribute ("selected") literally in the `selected` property of each `regions` element and then output it if present in the template.